# Python argumented decorator function

Tags: python, python-decorators

I have this example:

```
def decorator_function_with_arguments(arg1, arg2, arg3):
    def wrap(f):
        print("Inside wrap")
        def wrapped_f(*args):
            print("Pre")
            print("Decorator arguments:", arg1, arg2, arg3)
            f(*args)
            print("Post")
        return wrapped_f
    return wrap

@decorator_function_with_arguments("hello", "world", 42)
def sayHello(a1, a2, a3, a4):
    print('sayHello arguments:', a1, a2, a3, a4)

sayHello("say", "hello", "argument", "list")
```

The output is:

`Inside wrap
 Pre
 Decorator arguments: hello world 42
 sayHello arguments: say hello argument list
 Post`

I interpret this as follows: The `decorator_function_with_arguments` gets its 3 args. It outputs a function (`wrap`) that receives a function and outputs a function, which is the purpose of the decoration. So now `wrap` will be executed ("Inside wrap" gets printed), the decoration happens, `wrap` takes `sayHello` and puts it into `wrapped_f`, we return. Now if I call `sayHello` it will be the wrapped version of it, so the rest gets printed out. Ok, but now if i write this:

```
def argumented_decor(dec_arg1):
    def actual_decor(old_func):
        print("Pre Wrapped")
        def wrapped():
            print("Pre Main")
            print(dec_arg1)
            old_func()
            print("Post Main")
        return actual_decor
    return actual_decor

@argumented_decor("Decor Argument")
def f2():
    print("Main")

f2()
```

When calling `f2` I get the error message:
`TypeError: actual_decor() missing 1 required positional argument: 'old_func'`

Why? `argumented_decor` gets its argument, `actual_decor` will be executed, "Pre Wrapped" will be printed, `f2` will be wrapped. Now if I call it, it should do as the most inner `wrapped` function. Why not? I hope I could ask my question understandably. Thanks!

Comment: It should be `return wrapped` and not `return actual_decor` after `print("Post Main")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `actual_decor` function returns itself when it should return the wrapper function `wrapped`:

```
def argumented_decor(dec_arg1):
    def actual_decor(old_func):
        print("Pre Wrapped")
        def wrapped():
            print("Pre Main")
            print(dec_arg1)
            old_func()
            print("Post Main")
        return wrapped
    return actual_decor
```

Comment: i just realized it, how embarrasing ... at least the question shows how decorator works. Thank you